# File "/i18n/en_US.csv" does not exist in catalog page magento 2

Tags: magento, internationalization, magento2, magento-layout-xml

I have a custom theme in magento2.1. I have created a category and added one product under it. When I go to the category page to view that product in list, I got an error saying,

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): File "/i18n/en_US.csv" does not exist

Exception #0 (Exception): File "/i18n/en_US.csv" does not exist
```

From the error I understood that the language file is not existing. So I copied the language folder, ie : i18n folder from

```
vendor\magento\theme-frontend-blank
```

and pasted it in my

```
app\design\frontend\custom\theme
```

Then I deployed the static files. Still the error is showing. And homepage is working fine. Can any one please help me to sort it out?

Answer (score 0):

For `i18n` You can make it like this

- Make folder named with `i18n` in `app` folder
- Make sub folder same name as your theme like `custom` in `i18n` folder
- Make language pack folder(s) in `i18n -> custom` folder like `en_us` or `en_gb`
- Now your folder structure will like this `app/i18n/custom/en_us/`

Now in this your language package folder make below files, all files will be in this folder structure `app/i18n/custom/en_us/`

**app/i18n/custom/en_us/composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "custom/en_us",
    "description": "English (US) language",
    "version": "100.0.1",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-language",
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

**app/i18n/custom/en_us/language.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<language xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/Language/package.xsd">
    <code>en_US</code>
    <vendor>custom</vendor>
    <package>en_us</package>
</language>
```

**app/i18n/custom/en_us/registration.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE,
    'custom_en_us',
    __DIR__
);
```

After this put your **en_US.csv** in your language pack folder

- app/i18n/custom/en_us/en_US.csv

After than run this following commands

- `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
- `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
- `php bin/magento cache:clean`

Hope this will helps you

Comment: Thanks for your reply. And I wonder where my language folder exist? Is it the same in app/design/frontend/custom/theme/i18n ?

Comment: @hakkim delete it.. no need for it now.. you do direct from app folder now it will exists in `app/i18n/custom/en_us/en_US.csv`

Comment: I have changed as per your edit. Still it is not working. Don't know why.

Comment: @hakkim it is a standard way to override language pack.. it is working absolutely fine in many of my websites

Comment: @hakkim try to do it in fresh magento  2 installation.. and check it

Comment: Ok.. I will check with new installation and let you know.